# Avoid specifying all arguments in a subclass

Tags: python, constructor, arguments, subclass

I have a class:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,...........,x,y,z)
        #do some init stuff
```

And I have a subclass which needs one extra arg (the last `W`)

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self.a,b,c,d,e,f,g,...........,x,y,z,W)
        A.__init__(self,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,...........,x,y,z)
        self.__W=W
```

It seems dumb to write all this boiler-plate code, e.g passing all the args from `B`'s Ctor to the inside call to `A`'s ctor, since then every change to `A`'s ctor must be applied to two other places in `B`'s code.

I am guessing python has some idiom to handle such cases which I am unaware of. Can you point me in the right direction?

My best hunch, is to have a sort of Copy-Ctor for A and then change B's code into

```
class B(A):
     def __init__(self,instanceOfA,W):
         A.__copy_ctor__(self,instanceOfA)
         self.__W=W
```

This would suit my needs since I always create the subclass when given an instance of the father class, Though I am not sure whether it's possible...

Comment: If you have that many arguments, I would not use positional arguments but have them all/most of them as kwargs and use py3 '*' syntax `def __initi__(arg1,arg2,* kwarg1=..., ..., kwargx=..., w=...)` to force kwargs (=not rely on the order). Using `def __init__(self, arg1, arg2,*, **kwargs)` is shorter, but I do not like it because is messes up code completion in IDEs like pycharm. Apart from a bit of screen waste, what's the harm in writing out all the kwargs? You would anyway have to document them all in the docstring...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Considering that arguments could be passed either by name or by position, I'd code:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *a, **k):
      if 'W' in k:
        w = k.pop('W')
      else:
        w = a.pop()
      A.__init__(self, *a, **k)
      self._W = w
```

Comment: I like this idea, but I don't think the example works. Since `*a` causes `a` to [receive a **tuple**](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=kwargs#keyword-arguments), `a` doesn't have the `pop()` method. `a` needs to be converted to a list first. Also, if all of the arguments are passed by name, `a` is empty (so you can't `pop()` it).

Comment: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'pop'`

Comment: `a = list(a)` before `a.pop()`

Answer (score 7):

Edit:  based on Matt's suggestion, and to address gnibbler's concern re a positional-argument approach; you might check to make sure that the additional subclass-specific argument is being specified—similar to [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215923/avoid-specifying-all-arguments-in-a-subclass/2216157#2216157):

```
class B(A):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
      self._w = kwargs.pop('w')
    except KeyError:
      pass
    super(B,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

>>> b = B(1,2,w=3)
>>> b.a
1
>>> b.b
2
>>> b._w
3
```

Original answer:
Same idea as [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215923/avoid-specifying-all-arguments-in-a-subclass/2215992#2215992), using `super()` instead.

Use `super()` to call superclass's `__init__()` method, then continue initialising the subclass:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b

class B(A):
  def __init__(self, w, *args):
    super(B,self).__init__(*args)
    self.w = w
```

Comment: This solution requires that w has to be passed as the first arg or by name. The question has it as the last arg

Comment: @gnu nibbler: thank you for your comment. I have edited my answer to address this concern; similar to what Alex posted many hours ago :-)

Answer (score 2):

In situations where some or all of the arguments passed to `__init__` have default values, it can be useful to avoid repeating the `__init__` method signature in subclasses.

In these cases, `__init__` can pass any extra arguments to another method, which subclasses can override:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, *args, **kwargs):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        # …
        self._init_extra(*args, **kwargs)

    def _init_extra(self):
        """
        Subclasses can override this method to support extra
        __init__ arguments.
        """

        pass


class B(A):
    def _init_extra(self, w):
        self.w = w
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting something like this?

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
        # do stuff
        print a, d, g

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        args = list(args)
        self.__W = args.pop()
        A.__init__(self, *args)
```

Comment: well, this works for the very simplified version. But now B takes any number of args (less confining)...
Isn't there something more idiomatic?

Comment: B only kind of takes any number of arguments; it calls A and if A gets the wrong number it will raise `TypeError`. You could explicitly check  the number of arguments if you wished. I probably would in production code.

Comment: If you find the wrong number of arguments, you would raise a TypeError yourself anyway.

Comment: yeah, but the first error is a clear error (one that for instance, pylint, would recognize before you ran your code), but the error your solution invokes is one that would only be found at run time

Comment: P.S Another thing that I see as a disadvantage with this solution is that now B's __init__ docstring will have to be something like "this __init__ takes all of A's parameters, plus W as the last parameters" which is worse than having all the params written explicitly in the __init__...
Well, maybe you just can't have the benefit of both worlds :)