# Python: not specifying variables in subclass __init__ , problems with calling methods

Tags: python, subclass

I have a superclass that has a lot of arguments. I want to create a subclass that shares all of those arguments and adds additional one or two arguments. To ommit double-coding, I used a method specified in [Avoid specifying all arguments in a subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215923/avoid-specifying-all-arguments-in-a-subclass) :

```
class Container(Item):

  def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    try: self.is_locked=kwargs.pop('is_locked')
    except KeyError: pass
    super(Container, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def open(self):
    print "aw ys"
```

However, when I then try to call an object of a Container class:

```
> some_container.open()
AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute 'open'
```

It appears as if the some_container is not a Container() but rather an Item() with a single variable is_locked added. What am I doing wrong?

edit: My Item definition:

```
class Item(object:
def __init__(self,istemplate,id,short,long,type,flags,value,damagerange,damagereductionrange,weight): 
    if istemplate==False:
        self.__class__.instances.append(self)
    self.istemplate=istemplate
(... many variables like that...)
    self.id=id
    self.randomizestuff() 
    if istemplate==True:
        self.__class__.templates.append(copy.deepcopy(self))
```

Comment: What is your `Item` class definition?

Comment: Oops, sorry. Edited it into main post.

Comment: I assume `some_container` is created like `some_container = Container(...)`

Comment: I can't replicate your error, though I do have to fiddle with Item to get it to stop throwing errors right off.  Make sure you're actually instantiating Container and not Item, as is indicated by the error.

Comment: and just due to my curiosity/ignorance: why are you going through `self.__class__` ? Why not simply reach `templates` and `instances` through `self.templates` and `self.instances` ? If they are class attributes, they can be reached through `self.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some research it turned out I was in fact referencing not a container in some_container.open() but rather a dynamic item created by a function that creates instances of items from the same template. That function would define new instances as `Item(...)` rather than `Container(...)` since it was created before introduction of any subclasses.

```
some_container=Container(...)
some_container.open()
```

The above would work from the beginning, hence paidhima couldn't replicate my error.