# Require an option only if a choice is made when using click

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

When using [`click`](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) I know how to define a [multiple choice option](http://click.pocoo.org/5/options/#choice-options). I also know how to set an option as a *required* one. But, how can I indicate that an option `B` is required only if the value of option `A` is `foo`?

Here's an example:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--output',
              type=click.Choice(['stdout', 'file']), default='stdout')
@click.option('--filename', type=click.STRING)
def main(output, filename):
    print("output: " + output)
    if output == 'file':
        if filename is None:
            print("filename must be provided!")
        else:
            print("filename: " + str(filename))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If the `output` option is `stdout`, then `filename` is not needed. However, if the user chooses `output` to be `file`, then the other option `filename` must be provided. Is this pattern supported by click?

At the beginning of the function I can add something like:

```
if output == 'file' and filename is None:
    raise ValueError('When output is "file", a filename must be provided')
```

But I am interested whether there's a nicer/cleaner solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the particular case of this example, I think an easier method would be to get rid of `--output`, and simply assume `stdout` if `--filename` is not specified and if `--filename` is specified, then use it instead of `stdout`.

But assuming this is a contrived example, you can inherit from `click.Option` to allow hooking into the click processing:

#### Custom Class:

```
class OptionRequiredIf(click.Option):

    def full_process_value(self, ctx, value):
        value = super(OptionRequiredIf, self).full_process_value(ctx, value)

        if value is None and ctx.params['output'] == 'file':
            msg = 'Required if --output=file'
            raise click.MissingParameter(ctx=ctx, param=self, message=msg)
        return value
```

#### Using Custom Class:

To use the custom class, pass it as the cls argument to the option decorator like:

```
@click.option('--filename', type=click.STRING, cls=OptionRequiredIf)
```

#### Test Code:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--output',
              type=click.Choice(['stdout', 'file']), default='stdout')
@click.option('--filename', type=click.STRING, cls=OptionRequiredIf)
def main(output, filename):
    print("output: " + output)
    if output == 'file':
        if filename is None:
            print("filename must be provided!")
        else:
            print("filename: " + str(filename))


main('--output=file'.split())
```

#### Results:

```
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS]

Error: Missing option "--filename".  Required if --output=file
```

Comment: This seems to be very elegant solution. I tried to modify it a little and provide two more parameters to the class `OptionRequiredIf`. One would be  `depends_on_opt` which in this example would be `output` and the other `depends_on_val` which would hold `file`. I failed...

Comment: I'm afraid this solution doesn't work... When providing the `filename` it is not populating the corresponding variable. I posted a complete example on [gist](https://gist.github.com/drorata/1fa68b477d94aea5d37e87aa56e09295)

Comment: @dror, sorry I missed the return value, I was getting late for work, so I didn't test as well as I should have.  Glad it worked out and thanks for the edit...

Answer (score 3):

You can do the same thing with a custom validation callback:

```
import click


def required_with_output(ctx, param, value):
    if ctx.params.get("output") != "stdout" and value is None:
        raise click.BadParameter("--output requires --filename")
    return value


@click.command()
@click.option(
    "--output",
    type=click.Choice(["stdout", "file"]),
    default="stdout",
)
@click.option("--filename", callback=required_with_output)
def main(output, filename):
    print("output: " + output)
    if output == "file":
        if filename is None:
            print("filename must be provided!")
        else:
            print("filename: " + str(filename))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I think this is a little simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I extended the answer by Stephen, and made it more generic:

```
class OptionRequiredIf(click.Option):
    """
    Option is required if the context has `option` set to `value`
    """

    def __init__(self, *a, **k):
        try:
            option = k.pop('option')
            value  = k.pop('value')
        except KeyError:
            raise(KeyError("OptionRequiredIf needs the option and value "
                           "keywords arguments"))

        click.Option.__init__(self, *a, **k)
        self._option = option
        self._value = value

    def process_value(self, ctx, value):
        value = super(OptionRequiredIf, self).process_value(ctx, value)
        if value is None and ctx.params[self._option] == self._value:
            msg = 'Required if --{}={}'.format(self._option, self._value)
            raise click.MissingParameter(ctx=ctx, param=self, message=msg)
        return value
```

Usage example:

```
@click.option('--email', type=click.STRING,
              help='Settings for sending emails.',
              option='output', value='email', cls=OptionRequiredIf)
```

I was inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2216157/671013)