# How can i avoid repetitive calling of instance variables in Subclasses?

Tags: python-3.x, class, subclass

i was wondering if there is a way in Python to get rid of repetitive calling of instance variables , when creating subclasses.
for example:

```
class Name:
    def __init__(self,first,last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last



    def __str__(self):
        return f"Users first name is : {self.first}, Users last name is: {self.last}"


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"first:{self.first}, last:{self.last}"


class Cash(Name):
    def __init__(self,first,last,cash):
        super().__init__(first,last)
        self.cash = cash

    def full(self):
        return f"{self.first},{self.last},{self.cash}"



c1 = Cash("Exa","Cool",200)
print(c1.full())
```

Is it possible to call all instance variables (self.first,self.last...) from "Name", without having to mention them in the constructor of "Cash"

something like:

```
class Cash(Name):
    def __init__("all from Name" + new one ("cash" in this example)):
        super().__init__("all from Name")
        self.cash = cash
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid specifying all arguments in a subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215923/avoid-specifying-all-arguments-in-a-subclass)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can change the `Cash` class to look like this:

```
class Cash(Name):
    def __init__(self,*inputs):
        super(Cash,self).__init__(*inputs[:-1])
        self.cash = inputs[-1]

    def full(self):
        return f"{self.first},{self.last},{self.cash}"
```

but for a more general solution that covers all situations take a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215923/avoid-specifying-all-arguments-in-a-subclass).